# Spark streaming: keep the most recent value in a group

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have a stream like

```
+------+-------------------+------+
|group |               time| label|
+------+-------------------+------+
|     a|2020-01-01 10:49:00|red   |
|     a|2020-01-01 10:51:00|yellow|
|     a|2020-01-01 12:49:00|blue  |
|     b|2020-01-01 12:44:00|red   |
|     b|2020-01-01 12:46:00|blue  |
|     c|2020-01-01 12:46:00|green |
+------+-------------------+------+
```

I would like to use spark streaming to keep only, for each group, the most recent time.

With a spark dataframe I would use a window function as

```
val window = {
    Window
    .partitionBy("group")
    .orderBy($"time".desc)
}

df
.withColumn("rn",row_number.over(window))
.filter("rn = 1")
.drop("rn")
.show()
```

or alternatively

```
df
.orderBy($"time".desc)
.dropDuplicates("group")
```

What it is the best way to do the same operation in spark streaming and how to save the results in a way that only the most updated solution is stored?

Update:
I am trying to keep only one row per group with the most recent time. Is it possible to use a stateful transformation with `mapGroupsWithState` for the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

When doing an aggregation in Spark Structured Streaming you need to first define a `Window`. Through this [Window Operation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time) you are defining at which time interval your aggregation ("maximum time, grouped by column 'group'") will be calculated.

Let's say you are planning to get the maximum time in a 5 minute (non-sliding) window, then you would define:

```scala
val df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  [...]
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as group", "timestamp")

val dfGrouped = df
  .select(
    col("group"),
    col("timestamp"),
    unix_timestamp(col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").alias("time_unix"))
  .groupBy(col("group"), window($"timestamp", "5 minutes"))
  .agg(max("time_unix").alias("max_time_unix"))
  .withColumn("time", col("max_time_unix").cast(TimestampType))
  .drop("window", "max_time_unix")
```

It is important to note, that aggregations on the maximum value only work for numeric value, hence, the conversion to a `unix_timestamp` as shown above.

According to the [Output Modes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes), you can then choose the `update` mode to only get the updates on the groups. Make sure that your output sink (such as console or a database) is capable of handling updates and not creating duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for help. Anyhow, in your code column "label" is discarded. How to include it? In update/complete mode stream-stream join are forbidden

Comment: You have two options to include column "label": Either by using it as a groupBy condition or apply any aggregation logic to it.

Comment: I see your point. However, what I am trying to achieve is to keep only the most recent row for each group, so I cannot perform any aggregation on that column

Comment: I guess one should somehow compare pairs of timestamps per group and discard the one which is older and continue iteratively until only one row is left, or something similar